# Depending upon a Gihub repo for scala-js cross-build

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I'm attempting to build a scala-js project which includes a GitHub repo as a dependency. From reading [this page](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse) and [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658583/how-to-set-up-a-dependency-between-two-scala-js-cross-projects-in-a-multi-module) it appears that this should be done using a `ProjectRef` and then including in in the cross-project using `jsConfigure`. See below:

```
name := "My Project root project"

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).
  aggregate(myProjectJS, myProjectJVM).
  settings(
    publish := {},
    publishLocal := {}
  )

lazy val myProject = crossProject.in(file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "myProject",
    version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.4",
    testFrameworks += new TestFramework("utest.runner.Framework"),
    resolvers ++= Seq(
      "Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
    ),
    libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %%% "spire" % "0.14.1",
    libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "utest" % "0.6.0" % Test,
    libraryDependencies += "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "3.7.1" % Test
  ).
  jsConfigure(_.dependsOn(rxscalajs)).
  jsSettings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.3",
    jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "rxjs" % "5.3.0" / "bundles/Rx.min.js" commonJSName "Rx"
  )

lazy val rxscalajs = ProjectRef(uri(s"https://github.com/LukaJCB/rxscala-js.git#master"), "root")

lazy val myProjectJVM = myProject.jvm
lazy val myProjectJS = myProject.js
```

However doing this causes linking errors with the other dependencies (`spire` in this case).

```
[error] Referring to non-existent method cats.kernel.Order.on$mIcI$sp(scala.Function1)cats.kernel.Order
[error]   called from spire.std.LongAlgebra.on$mIcI$sp(scala.Function1)cats.kernel.Order
...
[error] (myProjectJS/compile:fullOptJS) org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.LinkingException: There were linking errors
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: There's a lot of weirdness here -- I've never seen this GitHub-include mechanism before, so it's hard to say how it's affecting things. Note that the linked article says to put the GitHub reference under /project, which might be significant.

Comment: But I'm not sure that's related to your error. Linker errors tend to refer to functions that haven't been ported to Scala.js.  I would *guess* that the typeclass instance of cats.kernel.Order being referred to here is using a JVM function that hasn't been ported yet...

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by incompatibilities with the latest versions of `rxscala-js`. Changing `#master` to `#<commit corresponding to version 0.15.0>` fixes the problem.